# How to add an autotools package to Buildroot?

Tags: compiling, embedded, buildroot

I'm trying to add a package to buildroot, but I'm not having much success. The package I'm trying to add is an autotools package called scew. I've followed the buildroot guidelines about adding packages, and although the package is listed when `make menuconfig` is run, when I run `make` the package is missing from the final `rootfs.tar`.

I've also copied over another simple `.mk` file that's used to install `which`, and changed the variable names and URL accordingly. Here is my copy of `scew.mk`:

```
SCEW_VERSION = 1.1.3
SCEW_SITE = http://savannah.nongnu.org/download/scew/
SCEW_LICENSE = GPLv3
SCEW_LICENSE_FILES = COPYING

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

In the same directory I have `Config.in`, which looks like:

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_SCEW
   bool "scew"
   help
   google scew
```

I've also added the following lines to `package/Config.in`:

```
menu "My Packages"

 menu "Packages I Wrote"
 source "package/MyPackages/packagesIWrote/hello/Config.in"
 source "package/MyPackages/packagesIWrote/helloworld/Config.in"
 endmenu

 menu "External Packages"
 source "package/MyPackages/external-packages/scew/Config.in"
 endmenu

endmenu
```

This part seems to work, as the packages are listed and can be selected. The hello and helloworld packages are copies from a guide to adding packages, taken from this website (written in french):[Adding Hello Wolrd](http://www.linuxembedded.fr/2011/03/ajouter-un-package-dans-buildroot-en-5-minutes/)

The hello world packages also do not work. I'd be glad of any advice at all, as it seems I'm just going around in circles on this one, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19783795/how-to-add-my-own-software-to-buildroot-linux (more generic, focus on source in-tree).

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [this project](https://github.com/dywisor/buildroot-packages) there are a realy good examples.

Edit the `buildroot-packages/package/Config.in` to add your package

```
menu "buildroot-packages [external repo]"
    source package/hola/Config.in
endmenu
```

Add in a folder your .in file `buildroot-packages/package/hola/Config.in`

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_HOLA
    bool "hola"
    depends on BR2_PACKAGE_SOME_PACKAGE
    help
        hola is an example of a program build with autotools for to be added
        to buildroot

        http://stackoverflow.com/users/4059304/simonppg

comment "hola no needs any toolchain w/ dynamic library, threads"
```

add the .mk too `buildroot-packages/package/hola/hola.mk`

```
HOLA_VERSION = v0.0.1
HOLA_SITE = https://bitbucket.org/simonppg/hola
HOLA_SITE_METHOD = git
HOLA_AUTORECONF = YES
HOLA_DEPENDENCIES = some_package

$(eval $(autotools-package))
```

and follow the instructions in the [same project](https://github.com/dywisor/buildroot-packages) to install or uninstall the packages in to your buildroot directory.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing what seems to be the same issue: whereas other packages end up building an executable and then stripping it into the directory `./project_build_arm/my_device/root/usr/bin/` , the package I added gets built and then stripped into `./build_arm/staging_dir/usr/bin/` instead.

To work around this problem, currently all I do is copy the stripped binary from the wrong directory to the right one. It's not clever, it's not correct, but it does work (in a Band-Aid kind of way).

It seems as though whatever is going wrong is doing so in a fairly high-level way, so perhaps the above description will be enough for someone with better buildroot experience to diagnose the actual cause of the problem.

...or have you since solved it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

The staging directory is useful for headers and mid step tools needed to build the final image but not needed in the rootfs, it is also used for built stripped libraries and executables.

The copy from staging to the target directory `$(TARGET_DIRECTORY)` is usually done within the target rootfs configuration you chosen (eg: cramfs, squashfs, etc.), but often the list of the files to be included in the rootfs is in your platform configuration target (eg: generic, platform-something) in a plain text file.